# theoremprework Error with ntheorem

Tags: page-breaking, theorems

I have defined

```
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule}
\theorempostwork{\hrule\bigskip}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem{definition}[satz]{Definition}
```

and now i am able to write something like

```
\begin{definition}fooBar\end{definition}
```

but i am getting a weird behavior with the prework of the theorem! LaTeX sets the top `\hrule` on one page and the rest of the definition on another page! See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbLhS.png) what i mean. Althoug it is german you can see that the top hrule of definition 1.2.7 is on page 6 while the rest can be found on top of page 7 (pages have a header line in my layout!). Any idea how to move this hrule to the same page as the definition **without** using `\newpage` to have still a dynamic document?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24101/215)

Comment: But i do not understand how to fix this with my template. I have way too many theorem environments to fix them easily.

Comment: Philippe's answer to the linked question involved redefining the theorem environment. Does this not work for you? If not could you explain why not?

Comment: My environment is called `definition` and with `renewenvironment` the layout is screwed. Furthermore i have problems with the counter which in fact does not exist! Seems like i have to use `\clearpage` or `\newpage`...

Comment: As Phileppe's answer says, theorems are defined as lists and so there are break points in them. I'm not sure there's much more help we can offer without more of a complete example and more explanation about why the solution in that other question isn't satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `needspace` pacakge might help here. Have a look at the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{needspace}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\needspace{\baselineskip}\hrule} % note this line
\theorempostwork{\hrule\needspace{\baselineskip}\bigskip} % note this line
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem{mydefinition}{Definition}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydefinition}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydefinition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using **mdframed**:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mdframed}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt,
  topline,bottomline,leftline=false,rightline=false,
  skipabove=\bigskipamount,skipbelow=\bigskipamount,
  %innertopmargin=\topsep,
  innerbottommargin=\topsep
  ]{definition}[satz]{Definition}
```