# How to port this ntheorem solution to amsthm + thmtools?

Tags: theorems, amsthm, ntheorem, thmtools

Is it possible to reproduce this [pleasant theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/theorem-decorations-that-stay-with-theorem-environment) using `amsthm` and `thmtools`?

Comment: See [example 7 of `mdframed-example-default.pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the package `mdframed` for drawing the frame. The setting of the theorems can be done by your favorite package. After you setup your theorem environment you can surround the environment with `\surroundwithmdframed`. For you required style you can use the following definition whereby the short lines have a length of 0.25 cm. Of course this can be done more elegant.

<sub>To simplify the code I am using the `calc` library of TikZ</sub>

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@tfl@spare[1]{%three or four borders
    \clip(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);%
    \begin{scope}[mdfcorners]%
       \clip[preaction=mdfouterline]%
            [postaction=mdfbackground]%
            [postaction=mdfinnerline]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]($(O|-P)-(0,0.25cm)$)--(O|-P)--(P)--($(P)-(0,0.25cm)$);
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]($(P|-O)+(0,0.25cm)$)--(P|-O)--(O)--($(O)+(0,0.25cm)$);
  }%
\newrobustcmd*\changelinestyle{\let\mdf@tikzbox@tfl\mdf@tikzbox@tfl@spare}
\makeatother
\surroundwithmdframed[settings=\changelinestyle]{theorem}
```

Through this definition all options of `mdframed` are allowed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[]{theorem}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*\mdf@tikzbox@tfl@spare[1]{%three or four borders
    \clip(0,0)rectangle(\mdfboundingboxwidth,\mdfboundingboxheight);%
    \begin{scope}[mdfcorners]%
       \clip[preaction=mdfouterline]%
            [postaction=mdfbackground]%
            [postaction=mdfinnerline]#1;%
    \end{scope}%
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]($(O|-P)-(0,0.25cm)$)--(O|-P)--(P)--($(P)-(0,0.25cm)$);
    \path[mdfmiddleline,mdfcorners]($(P|-O)+(0,0.25cm)$)--(P|-O)--(O)--($(O)+(0,0.25cm)$);
  }%
\newrobustcmd*\changelinestyle{\let\mdf@tikzbox@tfl\mdf@tikzbox@tfl@spare}
\makeatother
\surroundwithmdframed[settings=\changelinestyle,middlelinecolor=blue,roundcorner=3pt,middlelinewidth=1.2pt]{theorem}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}%
If~$G$ is a connected graph of order $n\geq 3$ and size~$m$, then
\[
    g(G)\geq \frac{m}{6}-\frac{n}{2}+1.%
\]
\end{theorem}%

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try your solution as soon as i can, just wondering where the blue color was set?

Comment: The blue color is set by `middlelinecolor=blue`. Does the solution works for you? Would you accept my answer?

Comment: Your solution is great, I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve a similar result with amsthm+thmtools only. If you argue it's impossible, I'll be happy to accept your argument as the answer.

Comment: @juliohm: At the moment I don't have any access to LaTeX. However of course it is possible ;-) -- `thmtools` have a key `mdframed` which can be used.