# Multicol listings and ntheorem rendering wrong

Tags: formatting, listings, multicol, ntheorem

Given the quite long MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{listings}

\nonzeroparskip             % Create space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Remove paragraph indentation
\setlength\columnsep{0pt}   % for multicol: still too much space in between

% From here:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/theorem-decorations-that-stay-with-theorem-environment
\newcommand{\theoremhang}{% top theorem decoration
  \begingroup%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{.005\linewidth}% \linewidth/200
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(1.5,0)%
      \linethickness{0.45pt} \color{Black}%
      \put(-3,2){\line(1,0){206}}% Top line
      \multido{\iA=2+-1,\iB=50+-10}{5}{% Top hangs
        \color{black!\iB}%
        \put(-3,\iA){\line(0,-1){1}}% Top left hang
        \put(203,\iA){\line(0,-1){1}}% Top right hang
      }%
    \end{picture}%
  \endgroup%
}%

\newcommand{\theoremhung}{% bottom theorem decoration
  \begingroup%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{.005\linewidth}% \linewidth/200
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(1.5,0)%
      \linethickness{0.45pt} \color{Black}%
      \put(-3,0){\line(1,0){206}}% Bottom line
      \multido{\iA=0+1,\iB=50+-10}{5}{% Bottom hangs
        \color{black!\iB}%
        \put(-3,\iA){\line(0,1){1}}% Bottom left hang
        \put(203,\iA){\line(0,1){1}}% Bottom right hang
      }%
    \end{picture}%
  \endgroup%
}%

\newcommand{\theoremspace}{\needspace{2\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\theoremspuce}{\nopagebreak\noindent}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{}%
\theoremprework{\theoremspace\theoremhang\vspace*{-1.3ex}}%
\theorempostwork{\theoremspuce\theoremhung}%
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}




\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]%
{%
\noindent%
\minipage{\linewidth}%
\theoremspace%
\theoremhang%
\lstset{#1}}%
{\theoremhung\endminipage}

\begin{document}

Code Env:

\begin{code}
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
\end{code}

Theorem Env:

\begin{theorem}
Test. Test. Test. Test. Test. Test.
\end{theorem}

Multicol Code Env:

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
\begin{code}
left
\end{code}
\item[]
\begin{code}
right
\end{code}
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image: rendered output]

Where I have two problems:

1. The hang/hung bars do not have the same distance to text (In particular the space from end of theorem+listings to the hung below is too large. But there are also other problems: for example "Theorem Env:" to hung above)
2. The multicol environment is not left aligned (may be caused by itemize which is needed to have the listings side-by-side)

I tried a lot with vspace hackery, but for at least at one of the places a problem persisted ;(

And is it possible to have the multicols/itemize in a self-defined environment to have everything more compact?

best regards,
Markus

Comment: i believe that the `multicol` environment *is* left aligned, but the indentation of the `code` environment is a consequence of the fact that it's within an `itemize` environment.  even though the `\item` label is absent. space is left for it at the beginning of the line..

Comment: Thank you, yes I think so too. How can I avoid the itemize to indent? Most problems are in the vertical spacing. (For example, Theorem to hung is too close). Btw. the itemize is necessary so that the code blocks are side-by-side.

Comment: the only straightforward way i can think of to avoid the item indent is to get out of `itemize`.  one of the list-enhancement packages, i've forgotten which, has a "resule" facility that allows one to continue numbering in an `enumerate` environment, but you wouldn't even need that with `itemize` since there's nothing you need to keep track of.  just exit from `itemize` and go back in after the code block.

Comment: Do you mean that I just put `\begin{itemize}\item[]\end{itemize}` within the two code envs? Or is there a way to define column breaks in multicol without any itemize?

Comment: there is a command `\columnbreak` that you can use to break after the code on the left.  maybe even `\par` would work.

Comment: An earlier comment of mine has a bad typo: "resule" should be "resume".

Comment: Note: I removed the memoir tag as the question is not related to `memoir`

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to have vspace within

```
\theorempostwork{\vspace{-1em}\theoremspuce\theoremhung}
```

Initially I tried to add the vspace to theoremspuce, where it did not work.