# How to make "rule with hooks"

Tags: rules, line

I guess this is a very basic question but I didn't find anything. Also didn't know what to search for, sry for the stupid title.

How can I make a "rule with hooks", be it horizontal or vertical, with a certain lenght and thickness, such as

```
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
```

But like in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Theorem decorations that stay with `theorem` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24101/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update:

As requested, an environment for "hooked" text. The syntax is:

```
\begin{hooked}[<optional line configuration (TikZ syntax)>]%
              {<Hook length (below horizontal rule)>}%
              {<The amount the hook advances to the margin>}%
              {<The space between the hook and the text>}
Text
\end{hooked}
```

I added a space between the hook and the text. It looks better with a little space.

The code:

```
\newenvironment{hooked}[4][line width=1pt]{% Default line appearance
  \noindent\hspace{-#3}% Drag the hook left by \hookmargin
  \begin{tikzpicture}% Draw the opening hook
    %                                          V---V Why can't use 2#3 instead of #3+#3?
    \draw [#1] (0,-#2) -- (0,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3,-#2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \par% We need a \par to avoid text in the same line as the rules (thanks @Werner!)
  \vspace{#4}% Add a space between the hook and the text
  \def\closehook{% Defining a closing hook (for some reason, putting this in the \end{hooked} definition doesn't work)
    \par% And another \par here!
    \vspace{#4}% Add the same sspace as before
    \noindent\hspace{-#3}% Doing the same...
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [#1] (0, #2) -- (0,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3, #2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}{%
  \closehook% Inserting the closing hook
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{hooked}[4][line width=1pt]{%
  \noindent\hspace{-#3}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [#1] (0,-#2) -- (0,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3,-#2);
  \end{tikzpicture}\par\vspace{#4}%
  \def\closehook{%
    \par\vspace{#4}\noindent\hspace{-#3}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [#1] (0, #2) -- (0,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3,0) -- (\linewidth+#3+#3, #2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}{\closehook}

\begin{document}

\begin{hooked}[line width=1pt, blue, dash dot]{2em}{2em}{-1em}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{hooked}

\end{document}
```

### My previous answer:

Using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\hooklength}
\setlength{\hooklength}{1em}% The length of the hook below the horizontal rule

\newlength{\hookmargin}
\setlength{\hookmargin}{2em}% The amount the hook enters the margin to each side

\newlength{\hookwidth}
\setlength{\hookwidth}{1pt}% The thickness of the rules

\newcommand{\hookdown}{%
\noindent\hspace{-\hookmargin}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [line width = \hookwidth] (0,-\hooklength) -- (0,0) -- (\textwidth+2\hookmargin,0) -- (\textwidth+2\hookmargin,-\hooklength);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\hookup}{%
\noindent\hspace{-\hookmargin}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [line width = \hookwidth] (0,\hooklength) -- (0,0) -- (\textwidth+2\hookmargin,0) -- (\textwidth+2\hookmargin,\hooklength);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\hookdown

\lipsum[1]

\hookup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could/should create an environment which gets surrounded by your hooks.

Comment: This would probably not work correctly around the page boundary.

Comment: @Skillmon Done! (Sorry for the delay `:)`). If I may ask, why "should"?

Comment: @Werner Could you explain why, please?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have never used any drawing packages and thought this is so basic it doesn't need one.

Comment: As for environments: Yes in fact I am writing a script for myself and wanted to make a proof and an example environment with these rules like in the shown book page.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik because syntactically this cries for being an environment as it is *one* block of content *surrounded* by something formatting it.

Comment: @Wulfram It doesn't necessarily *has* to be done with TikZ, but its far more straightforward than playing with rules. To create something like that you can rename the `hooked` environment, create an `example` counter and add `\textbf{EXAMPLE \theexample}` after the hook.

Comment: @Skillmon Saying it like this makes sense `:)`. I just thought it was something more... Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Firstly, you require a `\par` in order for the block components to be set on their own line. `\lipsum` issues that by default so it doesn't show in your code. Secondly, [here is an example](https://pastebin.com/EnTYTCs7) that highlights what happens around a bad page break.

Comment: @Werner Thanks! I completely forgot that a `\par` could be necessary there. As for the page break, do you have any suggestion on how to fix that? Feel free to edit my post if you wish `:)`

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution with  `quoting` and `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quoting}[leftmargin = 0.75em, rightmargin = 0.75em, indentfirst = false,%
 begintext = \noindent{\centering\hspace{-0.75em}$\overbracket[1pt][1ex]{\hspace*{\textwidth}}$}\vspace{-1.1ex}\par\nopagebreak\noindent, %
 endtext = \vspace{-2.25ex}\nopagebreak\noindent\centering{\hspace{-0.75em}$\underbracket[1pt][1ex]{\hspace*{\textwidth}}$}]
  \lipsum[1]
\end{quoting}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]