# Different colorcoded theorems

Tags: color, theorems, framed

I'm using this code to frame my theorems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem} 

\usepackage{framed}
\newframedtheorem{beispiel}{Beispiel}[section]
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{{\color{gray}\vrule width 3pt \hspace{15pt}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{beispiel}
[Antwortzeit]
Unter der Antwortzeit eines Dienstes versteht man den Zeitintervall zwischen dem     Absenden einer Nachricht und dem Empfang der entsprechenden Antwort. 
\end{beispiel}
\end{document}
```

I'm searching for a way to encode different theorems (example, proof, etc.) with different colors. But every time I try to create a new command I seem to "overwrite" the colors globally.

What would the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option would be to define for each color a command which will behave as `\newframedtheorem`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem} 

\usepackage{framed}

\makeatletter
\def\newframedRtheorem#1{%
\theoremprework{\vskip\theoremframepreskipamount
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{%
  {\color{red}\vrule width 3pt \hspace{15pt}}}
  \framed}%
\theorempostwork{\endframed\vskip\theoremframepostskipamount}%
\newtheorem@i{#1}%
}
\def\newframedBtheorem#1{%
\theoremprework{\vskip\theoremframepreskipamount
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{%
  {\color{blue}\vrule width 3pt \hspace{15pt}}}
  \framed}%
\theorempostwork{\endframed\vskip\theoremframepostskipamount}%
\newtheorem@i{#1}%
}
\def\newframedGtheorem#1{%
\theoremprework{\vskip\theoremframepreskipamount
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{%
  {\color{green}\vrule width 3pt \hspace{15pt}}}
  \framed}%
\theorempostwork{\endframed\vskip\theoremframepostskipamount}%
\newtheorem@i{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\newframedRtheorem{beispiel}{Beispiel}[section]
\newframedBtheorem{theo}[beispiel]{Theorem}
\newframedGtheorem{exam}[beispiel]{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{beispiel}[Antwortzeit]
Unter der Antwortzeit eines Dienstes versteht man den Zeitintervall zwischen dem     Absenden einer Nachricht und dem Empfang der entsprechenden Antwort. 
\end{beispiel}

\begin{theo}[Antwortzeit]
Unter der Antwortzeit eines Dienstes versteht man den Zeitintervall zwischen dem     Absenden einer Nachricht und dem Empfang der entsprechenden Antwort. 
\end{theo}

\begin{exam}[Antwortzeit]
Unter der Antwortzeit eines Dienstes versteht man den Zeitintervall zwischen dem     Absenden einer Nachricht und dem Empfang der entsprechenden Antwort. 
\end{exam}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Or you can use `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem} 
\usepackage[style=0,ntheorem]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{%
topline=false,
rightline=false,
bottomline=false,
linewidth=3pt,
innerleftmargin=15pt,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
skipabove=\baselineskip,
skipabove=1.2\baselineskip,
}

\newtheorem{mdbeispiel}{Beispiel}[section]
\newtheorem{mdspiele}{Spiele}[section]
\newenvironment{beispiel}[1][]%
   {\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue]\begin{mdbeispiel}[#1]}
   {\end{mdbeispiel}\end{mdframed}}
\newenvironment{spiele}[1][]%
   {\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red]\begin{mdspiele}[#1]}
   {\end{mdspiele}\end{mdframed}}


\begin{document}

\begin{beispiel}[Antwortzeit]
Unter der Antwortzeit eines Dienstes versteht man den Zeitintervall zwischen dem
Absenden einer Nachricht und dem Empfang der entsprechenden Antwort. 
\end{beispiel}

\begin{spiele}[Antwortzeit]
Unter der Antwortzeit eines Dienstes versteht man den Zeitintervall zwischen dem
Absenden einer Nachricht und dem Empfang der entsprechenden Antwort. 
\end{spiele}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

With version 0.8 `mdframed` provides the commands `newmdenv`, `renewmdenv` and `newmdtheoremenv`. So you can simple use:

```
newmdtheoremenv[linecolor=red]{beispiel}{Beispiel}[section]
```