# Good LaTeX preambles for math thesis

Tags: best-practices, preamble, thesis

Can someone provide me an example of a nice preamble to write a math thesis? 
I am currently using

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\topmargin -15mm

\textheight 24truecm   
\textwidth 16truecm    
\oddsidemargin 5mm
\evensidemargin 5mm   
\setlength\parskip{10pt}
\pagestyle{empty}          

\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
```

Comment: The best preamble is the preamble, that does contain only these packages and definitions you are using. BTW: You should read [l2tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-english) to avoid obsolete packages like `t1enc` (use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead). And it would be better to use packages like [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) or [typearea](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea) to setup text area and margins. At least better use `\setlength` to set lengths instead of using low level TeX.

Comment: Paper and page dimensions are better set up by the [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. The [t1enc](http://ctan.org/pkg/t1enc) package is obsolete and should be replaced by the [fontenc](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) package.

Comment: See Kevin Klement's (@frabjous') comments here on why a standard preamble is not optimal. http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/another-sample-preamble/

Comment: @Seamus Couldn't agree with you more on this one, although there is value not to add too many packages until you have written 100 or so pages, as by then you know what you need.

Answer (score 17):

In general, I suggest to start with a preamble that is as small as possible and to add packages and/or custom commands as the need for them arises.

With regard to your code sample:

- Don't fiddle with `\topmargin`, `\textheight` and similar commands. If you want to change the margins of your document, use the [geometry](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) or [typearea](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea) packages.
- If you really must denote new paragraphs by additional spacing instead of indentation, replace `\setlength\parskip{10pt}` with the [parskip](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/increasing-paragraph-indentation-in-koma-script/14565#14565) answer for details.
- The `t1enc` package is obsolete -- use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead. See [l2tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-english) for other obsolete packages/commands.

Comment: Better yet, don't use **parskip** either, and keep the standard intentation. :)

Comment: @egreg: I've qualified my statement. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to the comments of the other posters. Just add packages as you need. A thesis preamble is bound to expand fast. Divide it into sections such as General, Typography, Mathematics, Commands etc. As the preamble grows some of these you will pass to a package say `moremath.sty`.

Keep the style simple, no fancy fonts. Under typography you can include `microtype` and `stmarysd`. Under mathematics you have included the basis and I will second Mico's suggestion of `mathtools`. Under commands put all your specials. For example under theorems you should include all your formatting decisions as well. As a bonus, here is some styling for theorems.

```
%% Theorems formatting 
\newtheoremstyle{itheorem}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{ }{#1\if!#3!\else\ \fi\thmnote{#3}}
\newtheoremstyle{icorollary}{}{}{}{}{\itshape}{.---}{0pt}{#1}
\newtheoremstyle{numcorollary}{}{}{}{}{\itshape}{.}{ }{#1\if!#3!\else\ \fi\thmnote{#3}}
\newtheoremstyle{idefinition}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{.---}{0pt}{}
\newtheoremstyle{ilemma}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.---}{0pt}{#1\if!#3!\else\ \fi\thmnote{#3}}
\newtheoremstyle{iother}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.---}{0pt}{\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{ilemma}
\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{itheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{iother}
\newtheorem{other}{}
\theoremstyle{icorollary}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{numcorollary}
\newtheorem{ncorollary}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{idefinition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{definitions}{Definitions}
\newtheorem*{defnorder}{Definition of Order}

%% Proof environment
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\upshape\bfseries Proof}
```

[image]

Keep the style simple and clean with minimal bold and don't use the standard LaTeX class.

Answer (score 7):

- In addition to the math-related packages you're already loading, you may want to take a look at the [mathtools](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf) package. It's a superset of the `amsmath` package. If you load `mathtools`, there's no need to load `amsmath` by hand.
- You seem to be comfortable with Computer Modern/Latin Modern fonts. If this assumption is correct, you may want to load the [lmodern](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty) package.
- Moreover, instead of loading the deprecated `t1enc` package, you should issue the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.
- You should take a look at the `geometry` package and its margin-setting commands, to let you simplify the setup of the page layout. (As of now, the collection of commands looks like it was thrown together haphazardly.)
- What I'd really want to question about your preamble is the use of `\pagestyle{empty}`. Does your school require this? If not, please do your readers a favor and delete this command, so that LaTeX can print page numbers.